# Simple fast 2-way encryption in php

Tags: php, encryption, cryptography

I am serving a few MP3 files from my site, which are over 1 MB in size. I doubt others are hotlinking to the file because my CDN charges are going up without much difference in visits.

I am looking for a simple encryption, so that I can change the filename every 3-4 hours. I a more interested in a fast 2-way algorithm than the strength of encryption. Can someone suggest a fast encryption for this purpose.

Is encyption using mcrypt fast?

Comment: Don't get angry on me but don't you think that changing the files' names is the wrong way to solve this problem? What about making a script (PHP) that will serv the file only if the requester is allowed (by checking session or something)?

Comment: I agree with Poni. +You can check referer or use a captcha instead.

Comment: I am always open to suggestions :). I can't perform any referral or session verification because the files are served from a CDN. Since I have configured for origin pull, only the first request gets passed on to my server, when it is loaded to the CDN.

Comment: If I block the first request, the files will not be served from the CDN. If I allow the first request, the files will be served from the CDN for all subsequent requests. The only solution I can think of is to change the url at fixed intervals to make the hot linked url obsolete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unclear why you want encryption for this. It sounds like you just want a way to generate a link that isn't predictable, except by you. Taking an HMAC of a secret key, timestamp, and file identifier should do that for you. You can then make the HMAC part of the file name, along with the timestamp and file identifier. Verify them in your PHP script by computing the HMAC again and checking it against the one from the URI.

HMAC is not encryption, it's actually authentication/integrity, but its secure when used with a reasonable hash. Normally, I'd recommend SHA-256 or better, but for what you're doing MD5 sounds secure enough. Finding HMAC-MD5 code shouldn't be a problem. MD5 speed won't be a problem unless you're generating LOTS (millions per hour) of links.

(Authentication/integrity in this case means that the HMAC can only be generated by someone with your secret key as well as the public timestamp & file identifier).

Comment: Thanks derobert. It is a better and cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with md5 with hash that changes(on interval) => http://phpsec.org/articles/2005/password-hashing.html

Comment: MD5 wouldn't work, because if someone gets the filename then they can access it anytime. I do not wish to rename the file on my server.

Comment: I did not understand your reply last time. I though you were referring to hashing the complete filename. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a md3 of sha1 hash (or other one) to encrypt the date (or something like that). Encrypt the date for a string that is valid till 0:00. Use sha1(date('Y-m-d-H')) to get a new key every hour.

Someone accesses the file with http://domain.com/&^CYFG&^%U^GU^VUVUIVB/filename.zip, and you check if &^CYFG&^%U^GU^VUVUIVB equals sha1(date('Y-m-d-H')). If not, the link is old.